# Invoke C# .NET Core Lambda from AWS CodePipeline Action

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

AWS CodePipeline allows you to invoke a custom Lambda from an action as described here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.htmltion

I am having trouble determining how my C# Lambda function should be defined in order to access the input data from the pipeline.

I tried numerous attempts, was thinking it would be something similar to below.  I have also tried to create my own C# classes that the input JSON data would be deserialized to.

> public void FunctionHandler(  Amazon.CodePipeline.Model.Job
> CodePipeline,   ILambdaContext context)

Answer (score 7):

I was able to find out a solution.  Initially the first step that helped was to change the input parameter for my lambda function to a Stream.  I was then able to convert the stream to a string and determine exactly what was being sent to me, e.g

> ```
>     public void FunctionHandler(Stream input, ILambdaContext context)
>     {
>  ....
>     }
> ```

Then, based on the input data I was able to map it to a C# class that wrapped the AWS SDK Amazon.CodePipeline.Model.Job class.  It had to be mapped to the json property "CodePipeline.job".    The below code worked, I was able to retrieve all input values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.CodePipeline;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace lambdaEmptyFunction
{
    public class Function
    {
        public class CodePipelineInput
        {
            [JsonProperty("CodePipeline.job")]
            public Amazon.CodePipeline.Model.Job job { get; set; }
        }

        public void FunctionHandler(CodePipelineInput input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine(string.Format("data {0} {1} {2}", input.job.AccountId, input.job.Data.InputArtifacts[0].Location.S3Location.BucketName, input.job.Id));
        }
    }
}
```